# else not executed after a while in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am not sure why but my else statement is not executed after a while, despite of my while statement is true so it executes 'pass', and after that should handle the false statement within the else but it does not.

```
describe = client_sc.describe_provisioned_product(Id=pp_id)
describe_status = describe['ProvisionedProductDetail']['Status']
while describe_status != 'AVAILABLE':
   pass
else:
   create_access_key = client_iam.create_access_key(UserName='Tom')
```

Comment: Please re-read [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question to provide *exact* value for `describe_status` inline in the code of the post (instead of some random array).

Comment: Do you know what the `while-else` syntax does? Also, how do you expect this loop to end, ever? You never change the value of `describe_status` inside the loop.

Comment: the status will change itself, not by me inside the code :) I am here executing an asynchronous task

Answer (score 3):

```
while describe_status != 'AVAILABLE':
    pass
```

If `describe_status` is not equal to "AVAILABLE", that loop will  run forever.

It feels like you meant to have an `if` condition, not a `while` loop...

Comment: I can't use a simple if condition because I need to wait for the first instruction to end outside of the code as I execute an asynchronous task. I just want to control the status of a task running outside the Python code so I guess that I would need a while here

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that you don't change the describe_status as it suggested

```
describe = client_sc.describe_provisioned_product(Id=pp_id)
describe_status = describe['ProvisionedProductDetail']['Status']
while describe_status != 'AVAILABLE':
   # If you make changes here - the while loop will work properly
else:
   create_access_key = client_iam.create_access_key(UserName='Tom')
```

As an example of work, try this:

```
describe = client_sc.describe_provisioned_product(Id=pp_id)
describe_status = describe['ProvisionedProductDetail']['Status']
counter = 0
while describe_status != 'AVAILABLE':
   counter += 1
   if counter == 5:
       describe_status = 'AVAILABLE'
       # hence the statement satisfies the criteria
else:
   create_access_key = client_iam.create_access_key(UserName='Tom')
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to change the status myself. I have executed an asynchronous task. The status changes itself, from "UNDER_CHANGE", then "CREATED" then "AVAILABLE". This is happening outside of my code.

Comment: @liyas Well if you use async tasks, you shall to use async tools for it.
asyncio.ensure_future() as an example.

Answer (score 0):

```py
while describe_status != 'AVAILABLE':
   pass
```

This will run perpetually. You are essentially saying, while `describe_status` is not available, pass. This loop will run forever if `describe_status` does not get updated.

It becomes a forever loop, a loop that will never stop. You will have to stop the loop before your `else` codes will execute.

You could try this:

```py
while describe_status != 'AVAILABLE':
      # Update describe_status here.
      describe = client_sc.describe_provisioned_product(Id=pp_id)
      describe_status = describe['ProvisionedProductDetail']['Status']

      # You could put a wait time here.

else:
     create_access_key = client_iam.create_access_key(UserName='Tom')
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to change the status myself. I have executed an asynchronous task. The status changes itself, from "UNDER_CHANGE", then "CREATED" then "AVAILABLE". This is happening outside of my code.